# Use locate to find name in directories only

Tags: command-line, grep, locate

If i lost a file I use locate a lot. Works perfectly and with grep you can quickly find back what you looked for.

However, often it generates a lot of output which is not always easy to filter. One instance is when searching for a lost dir when the name is used in the base of a lot of entries. Try searching all `bin` dirs for example.

Locate by itself has no option to only search for directory type entries, but it has a option to parse a regexp. Unfortunately I am no high flyer on regexp.

*What would the regexp be to parse to locate to show 1 occurrence of every `bin` dir, or can I better use a different pipe?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
locate -r '/bin$'
```

will only show paths that end with `/bin`. As `/` can't be part of a file name that is files and folders named `bin`.

Comment: The trick is in the $, but what does it mean, end of line?

Comment: As `locate` prints one path per line the end of line is the same as the end of the path. That is a `/bin` not followed by anything